# JavaFX Application: Why does a single left-click on MenuButton cause ContextMenu to flicker on-off?

Tags: java, javafx, contextmenu, menuitem, bluej

I do not understand why when I left-click the MenuButton that the ContextMenu does not simply appear and stay, or disappear when I click a second time like a visibility toggle. A short code example and what I experience is detailed below.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class BtnTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new MenuButton("Options", null, new MenuItem("test1"), new MenuItem("test2")), 650, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Testing Btn");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I run this simple code in BlueJ IDE, on Windows 10

1. If I click on the MenuButton, the application window seems to be focused then lose focus, and the button's ContextMenu appears and then disappears.
2. If I click a second time, the ContextMenu appears and stays (even if I click off the application window onto another program).
3. If I click a third time, the ContextMenu disappears.
4. If I click a fourth time, the ContextMenu flickers on and off again.
5. If I click a fifth time, the ContextMenu appears and stays.
6. If I click a sixth time, the ContextMenu disappears.

And this continues to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but the problem appears to be that the autoHide boolean property for the ContextMenu/PopupWindow is set to true by default. MenuButton uses a default ContextMenu when you click it to show the MenuItems.

I tried to setContextMenu for the MenuButton to a predefined ContextMenu, one with autoHide set to false, but this either causes an overlapping of events causing it to show then hide on click, or the ContextMenu is being set back to null by MenuButton?

Either way, I found a solution by switching to using a Button and a ContextMenu separately from one another, with the ContextMenu's autoHide set to false:

```
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public class BtnTest2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        
        Button btn = new Button("Options");
        
        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("test1");
        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("test2");
        
        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
        cm.setAutoHide(false);
        cm.getItems().addAll(item1, item2);
        
        
        btn.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, e -> {
            cm.show(btn, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
            e.consume();
        });
        
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(btn, 650, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Testing Btn");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```